# JAVA stdin numeric and > 0 check

Tags: java, stdin, numeric

I'm using while (!stdin.hasNextInt()) to check the entered value is a number.

```
while (!stdin.hasNextInt())
        {
            stdin.nextLine();
            System.out.println("It must be a numeric value, re-enter: ");
        }
        side_1 =stdin.nextInt();
```

Now I have to check also that if its a number is > 0. Is there anyway I can get it in the same while condition?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `nextLine()` does?

Comment: reads what's in the line, but doesn't check if its > than 0

Comment: `int num = -1; while (!stdin.hasNextInt() || (num = stdin.nextInt()) <= 25) { stdin.readLine(); } System.out.println(num);` This will loop until a numeric value > 25 is entered.